# METODO REPAINT DENTRO DE UN LISTENER DE UN BOTON EN UN JPANEL PRINCIPAL

Tags: java-swing, jframe

Estoy creando un juego, mi problema es que tengo un menú principal en un `JPanel` y desde ahí tengo tres botones: jugar, créditos, salir. Los demás botones me funcionan perfectanmente, mi problema es en el boton de jugar en donde quiero que empiece el juego (que ya es funcional) lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
btnJugar.addActionListener(e1 -> {
        Sokoban sokoban = new Sokoban();
        JFrame frameSokoban = new JFrame("Sokoban");
        frameSokoban.add(sokoban);
        frameSokoban.setSize(1000, 700);
        frameSokoban.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameSokoban.setResizable(false);
        frameSokoban.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameSokoban.setVisible(true);

        menúPrincipal.dispose();
        do {
            sokoban.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (true);
    });
```

El frame `Sokoban` se crea sin problema, sin embargo el método repaint tiene alguna especie de problema y no funciona, Si sacamos todo lo que tiene el botón al main funciona todo sin problema, pero no es la idea. Me di cuenta que puede ser problema del bucle porque si saco al método repaint del bucle si me dibuja el juego, pero al no repintarse no se puede jugar. Alguna recomendación? Ya no sé que más hacer.

Comment: asegurate de agregar un [mcve]

Comment: De principio, no deberías invocar `repaint()` fuera de la clase Sokoban, rompes el encapsulamiento! Sokoban con base en su estado debería saber cuándo actualizarse, o en su defecto implementar escuchadores.

Comment: No entendí jajaja